# How to run PHPUnit with different Linux user

Tags: php, linux, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

1. My unit tests are located inside a Vagrant machine
2. I'm using Xdebug with Apache on Ubuntu 18,
3. I use PhpStorm to run PHPUnit tests.

The issue is the unit tests are restricted to be run by "apache" user and the way I run them from the command line is:

`sudo -u apache phpunit tests/EmailFunctionsLargeTest.php --stop-on-failure`

and it works, but how do I simulate the `sudo -u apache phpunit` when using PhpStorm?

P.S.

PhpStorm runs the tests as vagrant user...

Answer (score 5):

Not possible yet. Feel free to add your scenario as a comment to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38656

Answer (score 3):

Create a file php_wrapper.sh at `/home/vagrant/php_wrapper.sh` with below contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /usr/bin/php $@
```

Replace the command with `sudo -u apache $@` if you want.

In your PhpStorm setup the remote interpreter as shown in the below screenshot. When you run phpunit, it uses the php_wrapper.sh as a PHP executable and runs seamlessly.

[image]